# How do I plot an implicit function?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot the implicitly defined function $u(x,\,t)=(x - u(x,\,t)\, t)^2$. How can I do that?

Comment: What does `ut` mean?

Comment: ut means u(x,t)*t, (value of function times t)

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for `ContourPlot`?

Comment: I am reading it right now, but i still don't know to implement nested part.

Comment: You can solve for u. Rearrange the equation as `Solve[x^2 + u (-1 - 2 t x + t^2 u) == 0, u]` and you have two solutions `u1[x_,t_] := (1 + 2 t x - Sqrt[1 + 4 t x])/(2 t^2)` and `u2[x_,t_]:=(1 + 2 t x + Sqrt[1 + 4 t x])/(2 t^2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we regard `u[x,t]` as a implicit function which define by the equation `u=(x-u*t)^2`. So we can use `ContourPlot3D` to draw the relations between the three variables `x,t,u`

```
ContourPlot3D[u == (x - u*t)^2, {x, -5, 5}, {t, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5}, 
 Mesh -> None, PlotPoints -> 60, AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Times", 15}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Okey, what if i wanted to make countourplot of function u? (not 3d, i mean 2d one, countour lines of fuction u(x,t).) 
Just inserting ContourPlot[u == (x - u*t)^2, {x, -5, 5}, {t, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5}] doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Von One way is project to x-t plane. `ContourPlot3D[u == (x - u*t)^2, {x, -5, 5}, {t, -5, 5}, {u, -5, 5},    MeshFunctions -> (#3 &), Mesh -> 50, PlotPoints -> 60,    AxesLabel -> {x, t, u}, ContourStyle -> None,    AxesStyle -> Directive[{Blue, FontFamily -> "Times", 15}],    ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"] /. {Graphics3D ->     Graphics, {x_Real, t_Real, u_Real} -> {x, t}}`

Answer (score 2):

For the 2D contour plots

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = u[x, t] == (x - u[x, t]*t)^2;

sol = Solve[eqn, u[x, t]] // Simplify

(* {{u[x, t] -> (1 + 2 t x - Sqrt[1 + 4 t x])/(2 t^2)}, {u[x, t] -> (
   1 + 2 t x + Sqrt[1 + 4 t x])/(2 t^2)}} *)
```

Verifying the solutions,

```
eqn /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True} *)

Column[
 ContourPlot[#, {x, -4, 4}, {t, -4, 4},
    PlotLegends -> Automatic,
    ImageSize -> Medium,
    FrameLabel -> Automatic,
    PlotPoints -> 50,
    PlotLabel -> Style[StringForm["``", #], Bold, 14]] & /@
  (u[x, t] /. sol)]
```

[image]